# "On me vient d'appeler" ou "On vient de m'appeler" ?

Tags: pronoms, auxiliaires, futur-proche

"On me vient d'appeler" ou "On vient de m'appeler" ? Plus généralement, où place-t-on des pronoms COD et COI avec les constructions "venir de / être en train de / aller faire qqch" ? Autrement dit: doit-on considérer "vient" comme un verbe auxiliaire (comme "On m'a appelé") ou non?

**Update**
Pour le formuler en façon plus formelle:
aux temps composés le COD (complement d'objet direct, comme *me* dans mon exemple) vient avant de l'auxilaire (*On m'a appelé*), alors que dans les constructions infinitives il vient normalement avant le verbe, dont il est l'objet (*on essaie de m'appeler*). Dans le cas de *venir de* il ne s'agit ni de l'auxilaire (typique), ni d'un verbe avec un sens indépendant.

**Update 2**
Pour prendre un perspective un peu plus large (en réponse à la réponse excellente par @None):
Il s'agit de périphrases verbales en français, et la place  des compléments peut paraître tout à fait naturelle à un francophone. Par contre, dans beaucoup d'autres langues on utilise des auxiliaires afin d'exprimer les même aspects verbaux (par exemple, en anglais, on dit: *I have just finished it. = Je viens de le finir*, *I am reading it = Je suis en train de le lire*").

Comment: Je suis ni expert ni natif, mais dans votre exemple, « me » est l'objet de « appeler » et donc, on dirait « on vient de m'appeler ». C'est-à-dire: il n'est pas un auxiliaire dans ce sens-là.

Comment: @DerekAllums dans les temps composé COD vient avant l'auxilaire, alors que dans les constructions infinitives il vient normalement avant le verbe, dont il est l'objet. *On m'a appelé* est l'exemple de première, alors que *on essaie de m'appeler* est l'exemple de dernière. Dans le cas de "venir de" il ne s'agit ni d'auxilaire, ni de verbe avec un sense independant.

Comment: venir de faire quelque chose est une expression idiomatique. Pour cela, on ne peut pas mettre le pronom entre venir et de. Par contre, appeler quelqu'un ne l'est pas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les pronoms personnels compléments se placent presque toujours **devant le verbe dont ils sont les compléments**. Donc quand on a un verbe conjugué suivi d’un infinitif, les pronoms compléments de l'infinitif se placent devant l’infinitif.

*Aller + infinitif, venir + infinitif, être en train de + infinitif* sont des périphrases verbales qui se comportent comme n'importe quel autre verbe.

- – Vas-tu lire ce livre ?  – Je l'ai déjà lu, je viens de le finir.
- – Quand vas-tu ranger ta chambre ? – Je suis en train de la ranger !
- – Qui va faire la vaisselle ?  – Je vais la faire.

Les seul cas où les pronoms compléments ne se placent pas devant l'infinitif mais devant le verbe conjugué (parce que l'infinitif dépend directement d'eux) sont :

1. quand ce verbe conjugué est un verbe de perception :

- Je l'entends jouer du piano.

2. avec les verbes *faire* et *laisser* :

- Il ne sait jamais ses leçons, et pourtant je les lui fait apprendre.
- Je le laisse sortir dans le jardin pour faire ses besoins.

On pourra aussi voir [cette page](https://parlez-vous-french.com/la-place-des-pronoms-complements/).

Comment: Il s'agit de phrase verbales en français, et le placement des compléments peut paraître tout à fait naturel à un francophone. Par contre, beaucoup des autres langues utilise des auxiliaires afin d'exprimer les même aspects verbals (par exemple, *I have just finished it. = je viens de le finir*, *I am reading it = je suis en train de le lire*"). C'est peut-être cette perspective plus large qui me perturbe...

Comment: @RogerVadim Tout à fait, ces notions sont culturelles avant d'être grammaticales et ce point particulier n'est signalé que dans des grammaires pour non francophones. Et pourquoi *laisser* et *faire* son "à part" ce n'est pas évident (ça l'est peut-être plus pour les  verbes de perception), c'est pour ça que j'ai cru bon de le signaler.

Comment: * laisser* et *faire* son**t** "à part"